# Ocaml Calculation and Simplifying polynomial

Tags: ocaml

I'm working on the Simplifying code which is doing

Combining like terms by adding or subtracting their coefficients. simplifying expressions involving multiplication, and distributing the terms if necessary. Arranging the terms in descending order of degrees (from highest to lowest). Ensuring that the polynomial is in the form  ax^n+bx^(n−1)+…+cx+d   where  a ,  b ,  c  and  d  are constants. If the coefficient of any monomial is 0, that term is omitted from the final expression.

And this is the task that how code should work.

```
6 takes in an expression as input, calling the reduction function should return an expression of monomials: × * (multiply x by max degrees) + × * ( next max degree) ...
• One way to do it:
• Use a data structure to represent this expression - it's given as an expression, but we can decide a new data structure to represent a polynomial. Only have a monomial of a given degree (store coefficient, and degree and then have a list of those items.
• Example: 23 + 322 + 5x + 5 - represent as a list of tuples:
• (float, int) list ~ [(1, 3); (3, 2); (5, 1); (5, 0)]
• Reduce function: takes an expression as input and returns a (float, int) list. Do it recursively
• Decode: (float, int) list -> expression
• Example: x * (2x + 1)
•Encode x, and then encode x + 1: X - (1.0, 1) ; then 2*x: (2.0, 0) (1.0, 1)
• List: [(1.0, 1)]
• As for the 1: [(2.0, 1)]
• Multiply function: takes in a (float, int) list -> (float, int) list
- (float, int) list
• Takes two tuples as input, for instance 2x, and then should return (2.0, 1)
Using two fold_lefts to yield the result here
• Add function: (float, int) list -> (float, int) list -> (float, int) list
• [(2.0, 1); (1.0, 1)] - 2x + 1. This merges the list.
•Example: (2* + 3a' + 5g + 5)*2
• [(1, 3); (3, 2); (5, 1); (5, 0)] * [(1, 0)]
• Example: [(1,4), (3,3), (5, 3), (5, 1)]
```

I worked on the code, Most of simplifying is working well but it has one error, I provided detail under the code.

```
(*ast.ml*)
type binop = Add | Sub | Mul 

type expression =
  | Num of float
  | Var
  | Binop of binop * expression * expression
```

```
open List
open Ast
open ExpressionLibrary

(*=====================================================*)
(* Define a type for monomials *)
type monomial = (float * int)

(* Helper function to multiply monomials *)
let multiply_monomials (m1: monomial) (m2: monomial) : monomial =
  match (m1, m2) with
  | ((c1, d1), (c2, d2)) -> (c1 *. c2, d1 + d2)

(* Helper function to add two monomials with the same degree *)
let add_monomials (m1: monomial) (m2: monomial) : monomial =
  match (m1, m2) with
  | ((coeff1, degree1), (coeff2, _)) -> (coeff1 +. coeff2, degree1)

(* Helper function to simplify a list of monomials *)
let rec simplify_monomials (monomials: monomial list) : monomial list =
  let rec add_to_monomials ((c, d) as m) = function
    | [] -> [m]
    | (c', d') :: rest when d = d' -> (c +. c', d) :: rest
    | hd :: rest -> hd :: add_to_monomials m rest
  in
  let filtered_monomials = List.filter (fun (c, _) -> c <> 0.0) monomials in
  List.fold_left (fun acc m -> add_to_monomials m acc) [] filtered_monomials


(* Helper function to simplify an expression to a list of monomials *)
let rec expression_to_monomials (e: expression) : monomial list =
  match e with
  | Num c -> [(c, 0)]
  | Var -> [(1.0, 1)]
  | Binop (op, e1, e2) ->
    let monomials1 = expression_to_monomials e1 in
    let monomials2 = expression_to_monomials e2 in
    match op with
    | Add -> simplify_monomials (monomials1 @ monomials2)
    | Sub -> simplify_monomials (monomials1 @ List.map (fun (c, d) -> (-1.0 *. c, d)) monomials2)
    | Mul ->
      List.concat (List.map (fun m1 -> List.map (multiply_monomials m1) monomials2) monomials1)

(* Helper function to create an exponentiation expression *)
let rec create_pow_expression (base: expression) (exponent: int) : expression =
  if exponent = 1 then
    base
  else if exponent mod 2 = 0 then
    let half_pow = create_pow_expression base (exponent / 2) in
    Binop(Mul, half_pow, half_pow)
  else
    Binop(Mul, base, create_pow_expression base (exponent - 1))

(* Helper function to convert a list of monomials back to an expression *)
let monomials_to_expression (monomials: monomial list) : expression =
  let rec monomials_to_expr_helper (monomials: monomial list) : expression =
    match monomials with
    | [] -> Num 0.0
    | [(c, 0)] -> Num c
    | [(c, 1)] -> Binop (Mul, Num c, Var)
    | [(c, d)] when d > 1 ->
      let variable_expr = create_pow_expression Var d in
      Binop (Mul, Num c, variable_expr)
    | (c, d) :: rest when d > 1 ->
      let variable_expr = create_pow_expression Var d in
      Binop (Add, Binop (Mul, Num c, variable_expr), monomials_to_expr_helper rest)
    | (c, _) :: rest ->
      Binop (Add, Binop (Mul, Num c, Var), monomials_to_expr_helper rest)
  in
  monomials_to_expr_helper monomials

(* Main simplify function *)
let simplify (e: expression) : expression =
  let monomials = expression_to_monomials e in
  let simplified_monomials = simplify_monomials monomials in
  monomials_to_expression simplified_monomials
  
(*=====================================================*)
  let print_simplified_expression expr_str =
  let simplified_expr = simplify (parse expr_str) in
  let stringified_expr = to_string_wo_paren simplified_expr in
  print_string stringified_expr;
  print_newline ();
  ;;

print_simplified_expression "3*x*x + 2*x - 5 + 4*x*x - 7*x";
print_simplified_expression "3*x*x + 8*x + 2*x*x - 5 - 13*x";
print_simplified_expression "(x-1)*x*(x-5)";
print_simplified_expression "(x-1)*x*(x-5)*(4*x*x*x-11+66*x)";
print_simplified_expression "x - x";
print_simplified_expression "x + x + 0";
print_simplified_expression "0";
```

```
(* Expected output
"7.*x*x+-5.*x+-5."
"5.*x*x+-5.*x+-5."
"1.*x*x*x+-6.*x*x+5.*x"
"4.*x*x*x*x*x*x+-24.*x*x*x*x*x+86.*x*x*x*x+-407.*x*x*x+396.*x*x+-55.*x"
"0."
"2.*x"
"0."
*)
```

```
(*Actual output
7.*x*x+-5.*x+-5.                          (*Correct!*)
5.*x*x+-5.*x+-5.                          (*Correct!*)
1.*x*x*x+-6.*x*x+5.*x                     (*Correct!*)
4.*x*x*x*x*x*x+-407.*x*x*x+86.*x*x*x*x+-24.*x*x*x*x*x+396.*x*x+-55.*x    (*Wrong!*)
0.                                        (*Correct!*)
2.*x                                      (*Correct!*)
0.                                        (*Correct!*)
*)
```

All output is working well except one.
Multiplication between many polynomials is not working properly.
it gives me a wrong constant. but the number of variable is right.

```
(x-1)*x*(x-5)*(4*x*x*x-11+66*x) -> 
4.*x*x*x*x*x*x+-407.*x*x*x+86.*x*x*x*x+-24.*x*x*x*x*x+396.*x*x+-55.*x
but it should be
4.*x*x*x*x*x*x+-24.*x*x*x*x*x+86.*x*x*x*x+-407.*x*x*x+396.*x*x+-55.*x
```

Comment: Hint: Both your result and the expected answer represent
`4 X⁶ - 24 X⁵ + 86 X⁴ - 407 X³ + 396 X² - 55 X`
You are misanalyzing the issue.

Comment: I would encourage you to use the toplevel of your choice (_probably_ utop) to analyze the output of your functions rather than relying on printing it to standard output. this can let you see the structure of your data in a more raw format which is helpful for debugging. Relying on compiling a whole program and printing data is all well and good if you don't have tools like utop at your disposal, but if you do, use them.

Comment: I found out where it has problem. but still no solution
If I put print_simplified_expression "(4*x*x*x-11+66*x)";
it gives me "4.*x*x*x+-11.*x+66.*x" as an output. which should be "4.*x*x*x+66*x−11." it looks like multiplication is happening even if it shouldn't be

Comment: An unrelated thought: it'd be awfully nice if that `Var` constructor took an `int` parameter that specified the power it's raised to. So you could map `BinOp (Mul, Var 1, Var 2)` to `Var 3` for instance.